# strange matrix result from if else loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix, igraph, adjacency-matrix

The code below to fill a matrix with 1 if the vertex is adjacent to another vertex and 0 otherwise. I used [this function for comparison](http://igraph.org/r/doc/are_adjacent.html) but the resulted matrix is strange !!

```
R
library(igraph)

#prepare random data

random<-matrix(c(1,2,2,3,3,4),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
graph<-graph.data.frame(random, directed = FALSE)
v1<-c()
v2<-c()
for (edge in 1:length(E(graph))){
ver1<-ends(graph = graph, es = edge)[1]
v1[edge]<-ver1
ver2<-ends(graph = graph, es = edge)[2]
v2[edge]<-ver2
                             }
    v1
[1] "1" "2" "3"

#Construct the matrix

n1<-matrix(,nrow=length(v1), ncol=length(V(graph)))
for(i in 1:length(v1)){
for(j in 1:length(V(graph))){
are_adjacent(graph, v1[i], V(graph)[j])
if(TRUE){
n1[i,j]<-1
        }
else{
n1[i,j]<-0
     }
                             }

                     }
n1
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1
```

While the resulted matrix should be:

```
n1
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1
```

since `1 is adjacent only to 2`, `2 is adjacent to 1 & 3`, `3 is adjacent to 2 & 4`, `4 is adjacent only to 3`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is your `if` statement:

Try this:

```
n1<-matrix(,nrow=length(v1), ncol=length(V(graph)))
for(i in 1:length(v1)){
  for(j in 1:length(V(graph))){
    adjacent_test <- are_adjacent(graph, v1[i], V(graph)[j])
    if(adjacent_test == TRUE){
      n1[i,j]<-1
    }
    else{
      n1[i,j]<-0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there another way to write the if statement to increase the efficiency of the program for huge data ?

Comment: Yes, use the igraph function `as_adjacency_matrix`

Comment: Yes but "as_adjacency_matrix" function used with the whole graph and I want to find the adjacency vertices for each vertex alone

Comment: The function will give you a matrix just like your code.  If you want to find for just a vertex, it will be a row of the matrix.